# How show the content of a div after the CSS inside is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'url.php',
    success: function(data){
        $("div#mainclass").hide().html(data).fadeIn(100);
    }
});
```

When the fadeIn triggers, I see for a very short time, the html flashing with no CSS-Style applied, before the CSS applies. This problem is only visible in Firefox, Chrome seems to be fast enough. How can I prevent the display, until the CSS is parsed and applied?

Of course, I already tried a few things, but no luck^^

```
$("div#mainclass").hide().html(data).delay(200).fadeIn(100); 
// With Delay -> Same problem
```

---

```
$("div#mainclass").hide().html(data).ready(function(){
     $("div#mainclass").fadeIn(100)
}; 
// Also the ready Function doesn't help here.
```

---

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try moving `$("div#mainclass").hide()` before the ajax call is made

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mainclass").hide().load('url.php', function() { $(this).fadeIn(100); });
```

Comment: @LudwigBrida - If this is done on first pageload you would have to solve that by setting `#mainclass` to display none in CSS, as javascript just ain't fast enough.